# HTML5 Canvas not displaying anything

Tags: canvas

I've written the code below but nothing is appearing on my canvas

```
<html>
   <head>
   </head>
   <body>
      <canvas id="c" width="200" height="200"></canvas>
    <script>
        var c = document.querySelector("#c");
        var ctx = c.getContext("2d");
    </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not drawing anything to the canvas.
You just grabbed it's context - now you need to draw something to it.

```js
var canvas = document.querySelector('#c')
var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d')

ctx.fillRect(25, 25, 100, 100)
ctx.clearRect(45, 45, 60, 60)
ctx.strokeRect(50, 50, 50, 50)
```

```html
<canvas id="c"></canvas>
```